# User reference in Drupal Content Body

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, users

I am Drupal newbie and I 'm trying to develop a feature to refer users in my Drupal Blog Entry content.

Please see screenshot with example: http://prntscr.com/2p5dtv

Browsing for solutions, I found [this](https://drupal.org/project/references) module, but I am not sure how I can use it to achieve my goal.

Any help will be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: You are going to need to research Drupal Input Filters, and there, look at basic string manipulation, eg, when the filter finds @USER_NAME, replace that text with a link to your user, eg <a href=/user/#>USER_NAME</a> or what have you.  Some places to start looking may be the https://drupal.org/project/customfilter or the https://drupal.org/project/mentions modules.  If you need it dynamic a la facebook, then you will have to look into autocomplete and AJAX and a lot of other coding fanciness.

Comment: A lot of other coding fanciness is OK. I am familiar with AJAX and dynamic html content manipulation, as well as with PHP, but I'm not good with Drupal.

Comment: Drupal will allow you to leverage that with a lot of built-in APIs.  Definitely look into the Form and AJAX frameworks and autocomplete functionality.

Comment: Is there any very basic example of that feature I need somewhere ?

Comment: Form api here:  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7, googling `ajax autocomplete drupal` gives tons of places to look for the ajax autocomplete functionality.  You'll just be needing to do it inside a form element's input, not just on the form element input, but it is doable.